# TCP flow exchange monitoring tools in Ruby on Rails Wanted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tcp, rubygems, monitoring

Does anybody know some tcp data monitoring tools in Ruby gems kind of [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/) in C?

I would like to check all of the http headers and bodies data exchanges in Ruby on Rails applications w/ this tool w/o writing any debugging codes. I think it is enough to see a standard log by Rails application to see between clients and Rails apps, but I want to see also data exchange between Rails application and some other external website other than frontend. e.g. Facebook/Google APIs data which are exchanged in background.

Any info should be thankful!

Comment: You want to inspect the packets coming into and going out of a Ruby on  Rails application? Why?

Comment: Because I think it is enough to see a standard log by Rails application to see between clients and Rails apps, but I want to see also data exchange between Rails application and some other external website other than frontend. e.g. Facebook/Google APIs data which are exchanged in background.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool you're looking for to inspect data exchange between web applications or with web APIs (at the HTTP level not TCP), is [Mitmproxy](https://github.com/cortesi/mitmproxy).

Answer (score 0):

The closest I found in Ruby land so far are [PcapRub](https://github.com/shadowbq/pcaprub) (which uses tcpdump's pcaplib under the hood) and [PacketFu](https://github.com/todb/packetfu) (which uses PcapRub under the hood).

Those however operate on the same abstraction level as [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org): They capture individual packets but unlike tcpflow, they don't understand sequence numbers and can therefore not reconstruct data streams in case of retransmissions or out-of-order delivery.

I'd be very interested in a Ruby gem that implements tcpflow as well. I wouldn't mind if it used native tcpflow under the hood, but would appreciate the convenience of gem packaging.